# How do I insert into a table if a value does not exist, but only for certain criteria? (MS SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, insert

Im very new to SQL but need to write a query to do the following.
Using MS SQL Server 2005.

```
Profile                  DefinitioninProfile         Definition
------                   -------------------         ----------      
ProfileID                DefinitionID                DefinitionID
ProfileType              ProfileID                   DefinitionType
ProfileName
```

In the definition table, defintion Type can be TypeA, TypeB ..... TypeZ.
I want to make sure that for a certain profile type, ProfileTypeA
the Definition has all the Types, TypeA -> TypeZ.

But some of the types already exist in the table, and I dont want to have duplicates.

```
So its something like
SELECT ProfileID from Profile where ProfileType = ProfileTypeA
FOR EACH ProfileID
   IF NOT EXISTS IN Defintion TypeA
   INSERT TypeA into Definition
   INSERT ProfileID, DefinitionID into DefinitionInProfile

   ...repeat for TypeB, TypeC...
END
```

1. I need to get all the instances where ProfileType = ProfileTypeA
2. Then get the first Profile.profileID
3. Then check the DefinitioninProfile table to get a list of DefinitionIDs where the
   profileID = Profile.ProfileID
4. Then for all those Definition IDs check if there is a definitionType called 'TypeA'
   if not insert it, if there is ignore it.
   Then do the same for 'TypeB', repeat for typec, .. typeZ

Go back to step 2 and get the next Profile.ProfileID and repeat 3 & 4 for that profile ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT DefinitionInProfile 
    (ProfileID, DefinitionID)
SELECT
    P.ProfileID, D.DefinitionID
FROM
    --All permutations of P and D
    Profile P
    CROSS JOIN
    Definition D
WHERE
    --Edit (added 2 rows)
    --But filter and lookup type -> id
    P.ProfileType = ProfileTypeA
    AND
    --End edit
    --But not where the defid is already there for that profileid
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * --or 1!!
        FROM
            DefinitionInProfile DP
        WHERE
            DP.ProfileID = P.ProfileID AND
            DP.DefinitionID= D.DefinitionID)
```

Comment: I understood it to be that you want have all combination of profile and definition and defintioninprofile. On a 2nd reading, you want it only for profiletypea. Did you get an error? Or

Comment: I didnt get an error.

I have edited my question hopefully to make it clearer.

Comment: It doesnt insert the missing 'typeA' 'typeB' ... into the Definition table?

Comment: You need a source of definitions to give the range of definitions.
If you add deftypea to deftypez manually, then the CROSS JOIN works.
It makes no sense to add deftypea to deftypez to definition for each profiletype... this is the point of DefinitionInProfile to deal with the permutations

Comment: I can see what you're saying, but its a database that Ive been asked to modify and I cant change the structure.